# English Sentence interpretation

Tags: expressions

Under the schedule of rates of a commercial contract it is specified that schedule of prices includes

"All rents, royalties, licenses, permits, permissions and any other fee, duty, penalty, levy, loss or damages payable on the excavation,​ removal or transportation of any material or acquisition or use of any right of way or other right, licenses, permit, privilege, permission or uses required for or relative to the performance of the work"

With the above, please clarify the royalty charges payable on excavation is included in the price schedule or not?

Comment: There should be a comma after "material".  The material is excavated, removed or transported; the "acquisition" is another matter. Maybe it needs ",or **on** aquisition...", meaning payable at time of acquisition.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in "royalties"? Is the omission of the other types of monetary outlays deliberate? Also, we would need to see the sentence that appears immediately prior to this list.

Answer (score -1):

From a grammatical and idiomatic point of view, the phrase "payable on the excavation" likely modifies only "fee, duty, penalty, level, loss, or damages" because those things are said to be payable.  "Royalties" is lumped in with "licenses, permits, and permissions," which aren't payable but obtained.  But that leaves "all" modifying "royalties," which means that any royalties are included in the price, no matter when they must be paid, pre- or post-excavation.

Be warned that opinons on English usage isn't legal advice.  If you've unsure of the wording you're about to agree to, consult a lawyer who specializes in contract and business law in your jurisdiction.